# Receive a Json array all 30 seconds and check the list with the last one received

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm building a IRC Bot (PircBot) and want to make a follower - thanks function for twitch.tv.

With this [json](https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/yeroise/follows) link im able to call the List of ppl which currently are following Channel XY.

Ive Made up already the Code to receive the list all X seconds here:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;





private String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }



  public void StreamChecker() throws IOException, JSONException {
    json = readJsonFromUrl("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/"+ownerchannel +"/follows");
    System.out.println(json.get("_total"));
```

And here is the Timer that Calls the Action all X minutes:

```
  public void LiveChecker() { 
    TTtwl.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                StreamChecker();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(json.toString());
        }
    }, 1000*30, 1000*30);
}
```

Now my Question is simple:

How is the best way to check the list i received earlier with the one i received now if there are any new names (following people) so i can call them out in a IRC message?
Greetings

Comment: Looking at the JSON object you want to handle: `"created_at":"2014-02-23T09:45:25Z"` just use this time to know when the users started subscribing to you, if it's between the last and the current check the user is new and can get reported to your IRC. edit: Or create a collection with know subscribers and one with the current list and compare those, new ones can be sent to IRC and the initial list.

Comment: Well, with the above code im calling the amount of following useer from my channel. i just need to save that amount in an different string and then, everytime the lsit got renewed just check if the number is > then the saved one from last time. if it is is and thats the part i need help now: i want to call the json with all the names and possibly get the name of the last entry. hwo is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I learned you already know how to get the total number of Subscribers.

Just push this approach a little further and you will arrive where you wanted to go to:

```
private static HashMap<Integer, String> currentFollowers = 
                                        new HashMap<Integer, String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get the string from the web
    String jsonInputString = "";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonInputString);

    // check total followers (this is what you should know)
    Integer totalFollowers = json.getInt("_total");
    System.out.println("Total followers: " + totalFollowers);

    // check if there are new followers (exercise: what about unsubscribers?)
    if(totalFollowers > currentFollowers.size()) {
        // get the array of followers
        JSONArray followerArray = json.getJSONArray("follows");

        // go through it and check if the user is in the HashMap
        for(int i = 0; i < followerArray.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject follower = new JSONObject(
                                        followerArray.get(i).toString()
                                  );
            JSONObject userObject = follower.getJSONObject("user");
            Integer id = userObject.getInt("_id");

            if(!currentFollowers.containsKey(id)) {
                // here you have not to print but to sendit to IRC
                String name = userObject.getString("display_name");
                System.out.println("New subscriber: " + name + ", welcome!");
                currentFollowers.put(id, name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you could also use lists, compare the names, even create a class TwitchUser and save all things there to compare them and make it easier. You can also create a second collection you fill new each time (a bit like a "double buffered" approach) and compare both collections then.

If you just have problems with understanding how json works (i.e. getting the right objects) I recommend just having a look at the [javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/package-summary.html) of the classes you seem to use, maybe also directly at [json.org](http://json.org), which has nice diagrams explaining it. Also you should try

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
System.out.println(json.toString(2));
```

which indents the String and provides a great overview over the structure.